# BeautifulSoup: get tag name of element itself, not its children

Tags: tags, beautifulsoup

I have the below (simplified) code, which uses the following source:

```
<html>
    <p>line 1</p>
    <div>
        <a>line 2</a>
    </div>
</html>

soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><p>line 1</p><div><a>line 2</a></div></html>')
ele = soup.find('p').nextSibling
somehow_print_tag_of_ele_here
```

I want to get the tag of ele, in this case "div". However, I only seem to be able to get the tag of its children. Am I missing something simple? I thought that I could do ele.tag.name, but that is an exception since tag is None.

```
#Below correctly prints the div element "<div><a>line 2</a></div>"
print ele

#Below prints "None". Printing tag.name is an exception since tag is None
print ele.tag 

#Below prints "a", the child of ele
allTags = ele.findAll(True)
for e in allTags:
    print e.name
```

At this point, I am considering doing something along the way of getting the parent of ele, then getting the tags of parent's children and, having counted how many upper siblings ele has, counting down to the correct child tag. That seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`ele` is already a tag, try doing this:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><p>line 1</p><div><a>line 2</a></div></html>')
print(soup.find('p').nextSibling.name)
```

So in your example it would be just

```py
print(ele.name)
```

Comment: @user984003 see the edit, I proposed an example, but it should work the way you asked to. the important part is that you should not do .tag.name, just .name directly

Comment: BUT, I see, I already have a tag so I do: print ele.name. I tested it and it worked:) I WAS missing something simple! If you edit your answer to say ele.name then I will check it as the correct answer when I can.

Comment: Is it possible to use ele.name in a condition? Something like:
`if ele.name is 'a':`
Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @zimmi I was able to use ele.name in a condition with no issues, I did use ele.name == 'a' though. With the `is` operator, you are identity testing vs. equality testing with `==`.

Comment: Thanks ! And how to get the content `line 2` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access anything inside an element as if accessing a dictionary.
Let's say you have an element like this one.

```
<input id="__VIEWSTATE3" name="__VIEWSTATE3" type="hidden" value="MwqzeTH4"/>
```

You can access each property like this

```
print(elem["id"])
# prints __VIEWSTATE3
```

Answer (score 0):

print(soup.find('h1',id_='pdp_product_title'))
it doesnot print any detail please solved this

`<h1 id="pdp_product_title" class="headline-2 css-zis9ta" data-test="product-title">Nike Air Force 1 Shadow</h1>`